# Instance of object in flex-bison c++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker-errors, bison, flex-lexer

My *`main.hpp`* looks like this :

```
#include "json.tab.h"
#include "ob.hpp"

extern Ob *ob;
```

In my *`test.l`*, I wrote :

```
%{
    #include "main.hpp"
%}


%token  KEY
%token  COMMA

%%
KEY_SET         : KEY                                                 {ob->someOp();}
                | KEY_SET COMMA KEY                                   {ob->someOp();}
%%
```

But this gives me :

```
C:\......c:(.text+0x37a): undefined reference to `ob'
C:\......c:(.text+0x38e): undefined reference to `Ob::someop()'
```

So how can I call that Ob object from anywhere in my parser?

My Ob class(*`Ob.hpp`*) :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#ifndef O_H_
#define O_H_

using namespace std;

class Ob {
public:
    Ob();
    ~Ob();
    someop();
};

#endif /*O_H_*/
```

And *`Ob.cpp`*:

```
Ob::someop()
{
    cout << "c++ is lit" << endl;
}
```

Now I have made all method in Ob static, so that no need to have an instance. And my build rule looks something like this :

```
g++ lex.yy.c test.tab.c main.cpp *.hpp -o test.exe
```

And I made the parser generator plain, without any method call, and it works fine, no error, no warning :

```
%%
KEY_SET         : KEY     
                | KEY_SET COMMA KEY    
%%
```

And when I added `{Ob::someOp();}`, then it gives me the same error again.

All of my codes are here : https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/6d0ea58cd70fbe255a4834eb46f2e1fd

Comment: The error messages ae sayig that you haven't defined `ob` or `Ob::someop()`. You haven't shown any code which defines either of these things. So at the moment it's not surprising to me that you get these errors. Are you claiming that you have defined `ob` and `Ob::someop()`? If so then you should show that code. Since these are linker errors some details on how you build your program as well would help.

Comment: @john I have added all the code I think I need, can you check again once ?

Comment: Well if that is all the code then there is still no definition for `ob`, and `Ob::someop()` is a syntax error (the return type is missing, presumably it should be `void Ob::someop()`). So I can only assume that you are not actually compiling Ob.cpp, since otherwise you would have seen the compiler error messages.

Comment: @john , 3rd sloc of `main.hpp` has a reference of Ob, with extern keyword. And `test.l` is importing or including `main.hpp`.. shouldn't `test.l` have reference of Ob ?? And I have tried with void keyword too.. and final build rule has `g++ lex.yy.c test.tab.c main.cpp -o test.exe`, which contains `main.cpp`. And it contains `main.hpp`..

Comment: 1. This is C++, and therefore not [tag:c]. 2. There is nothing here that declares an *instance* of the missing object. A class declaration does not declare an instance. 3. Your `Ob.cpp` file doesn't compile: either you have ignored the error or you aren't even compiling it.

Comment: `extern Ob* ob;` is a declaration not a definition. You need a definition as well. If you program with multiple files and global variables you need to know the difference between declarations and definitions. And as your command line shows you aren't compiling Ob.cpp, so that explains the second error, just add `Ob.cpp` to the command line.

Comment: I have updated the question, can you guys check it out again ??

Comment: When you write `extern Ob *ob;` you are telling the compiler that the variable `ob` (of type `Ob*`) is defined *somewhere else* (i.e., it it external to this translation unit). But that's not the case. You don't define `ob` anywhere (or if you do, you're not showing the relevant file), so it is undefined. If you use it, you'll get a linker error.

Comment: Also: (1) this problem has nothing to do with flex or bison. That's just confusing the issue (and probably confusing you, too). First figure out how to write a C++ program spread over several files. Then you can add flex and bison to the mix. (2) Never ask GCC to compile a header file (`*.hpp`) unless you know what you're asking for. (What you're asking for is a precompiled header. If you don't know what that is, you don't want to ask for one to be built.) (3) Ob.cpp cannot be compiled: `<stdin>:13:12: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘someop’ with no type [-fpermissive]`. Please fix that

Comment: I have added all of my codes here : https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/6d0ea58cd70fbe255a4834eb46f2e1fd , please check @rici

Comment: See my earlier comment about "compiling" header files. Don't do that. Remove `*.hpp`. But do ensure that you are compiling all source files (which includes ob.cpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser generator looks like this :

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include "main.h"
    #include "json.h"
    using namespace Maifee;
%}
...
meaw           : INTEGER               {Json::ok();}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef JSON_H
#define JSON_H

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

namespace Maifee{

class Json {
public:
    static void ok();
};
#endif // JSON_H
```

The cpp file :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "json.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Maifee;

void Json::ok()
{
    //whatever here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass all the the `.cpp` files, and no `.hpp`, to the compile command. The `.hpp` will be automatically included by the preprocessor. If you don't do it (you are not including `Ob.cpp` in your command), then it can't find the definition of the functions contained in them.

So your compilation command should be this:

```sh
g++ lex.yy.c test.tab.c main.cpp Ob.cpp -o test.exe
```

Comment: sorry to say, but this doesn't work... still undefined.. and I have updated the question, can you check once again ??

Comment: There is nothing in the question to suggest that this is the problem.

Comment: Look the compilation command and look the error it gives. That does suggest that the undefined references are provoked by the lack of a source file.

Comment: I don't think it's due to build, as I have tried **`g++ lex.yy.c test.tab.c main.cpp *.hpp -o test.exe`** too... I think the problem is in - *forward declaration*, - *lack of knowledge to write c++ code well, as I don't know how to structure those codes, maybe I'm messing by importing something extra somewhere or i'm importing less*.. I have updated the question and added my working directory in gist, please check it out... https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/6d0ea58cd70fbe255a4834eb46f2e1fd#file-readme-md

Comment: Read again my answer and try my command and tell me the results.

Comment: @Miguel really appreciate your answer, but as it is partial, I'm just upvoting it.. actually I had two problem here, one build command, that you resolved... other one is writing correctly in C++, please check my answer